# How to translate entire site, source code and all

Tags: translate

Sites like http://www.dressup24h.com have added links in the form of flags that act as links to translated pages. Which is easy enough. But how to translate the entire page and the source code so that the page registers on google as a separate language to the original.

Eg. transforms your meta tags and title and all text to new language.

Answer (score 0):

Every page contains some text in one way or another. Just translate all these texts.

As for automatization - most pages use Google Translation API to that, usually violating it's terms

Comment: and the translation will suck: for instance on that site "thin girl with guitar" is translated in Italian in something that means "girl with thin guitar".